# According to the Catholic commentators, was Mary the original candidate for mother of God?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, incarnation

Is it possible to think that another woman before Mary had been asked by an angel to be the mother of God, but the incarnation did not happen at that time because she rejected the proposal?

In the other words, does the Catholic Church teach that Mary the first woman asked to be mother of God?

Comment: The answer would depend on which tradition.  Catholics would probably say, "yes" because they hold that her conception was immaculate.  Protestants would say, "no", that Mary was not chosen because she was holy or different from other devout women.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I would be curious rather in the catholic position. What about Eve? Wasn't she without sins at the beginning? Could Eve have become mother of God?

Comment: You may want to clarify exactly what you mean by "mother of God". I'm assuming you mean simply the one who gave birth to Jesus, the Incarnation of God. If Eve had not sinned, the Incarnation presumably would have been unnecessary. Since she did sin, she wouldn't have met the Roman Catholic's requirements to be Jesus' mother. As an Evangelical Christian, I doubt if God would have asked someone to be Jesus' mother unless He knew she would agree.

Comment: @disciple I've heard somewhere that God would probably have become incarnate even if the fall never happened, so as to unite human and divine natures and allow us to experience theosis. I think it was an Eastern Orthodox blog somewhere on the interwebs

Comment: I think this a duplicate: [Why did God choose Mary?](//christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15621)

Comment: The title says "first", the body says "only" - the OP really needs to choose which they want to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Catholic teaching and theology, there is what is called *a vocation*<sup>1</sup>, i.e. *a calling*. From all eternity, God has called each one of us to be what he wanted each one of us to be. This calling is unique and unrepeatable precisely because each person is unique and unrepeatable<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1. *We define personal vocation as God's call and plan for one's entire life.* cf. [GERMAIN GRISEZ ON PERSONAL VOCATIONS | EWTN](http://www.ewtn.com/library/Theology/ZVOCATIO.HTM).</sup>
<sup>2. cf. b. Unique and unrepeatable | B. OPENNESS TO TRANSCENDENCE AND UNIQUENESS OF THE PERSON in [COMPENDIUM OF THE SOCIAL DOCTRINE OF THE CHURCH](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/pontifical_councils/justpeace/documents/rc_pc_justpeace_doc_20060526_compendio-dott-soc_en.html).</sup>

The following sample biblical passages are offered in support:

> [Matt 20:23
>   (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+20%3A23&version=RSVCE)
>   23 He said to them, “You will drink my cup, but to sit at my right
>   hand and at my left is not mine to grant, but it is for those for whom
>   it has been prepared by my Father.”

And

> [Jn 15:16
>   (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+15%3A16&version=RSVCE)
>   16 You did not choose me, but I chose you and appointed you that you
>   should go and bear fruit and that your fruit should abide; so that
>   whatever you ask the Father in my name, he may give it to you.

And

> [Is 43:1
>   (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+43%3A1&version=RSVCE)
>   43 But now thus says the Lord, he who created you, O Jacob, he who
>   formed you, O Israel: “Fear not, for I have redeemed you; I have
>   called you by name, you are mine.

Thus Mary was God's choice to be his Mother and now is the only choice because she said yes! And we thank God and her for that.

*What could God have done if Mary had said no?*

*With God all things are possible*<sup>3</sup>. In Catholic teaching and theology there are infinite number of ways by which God could have accomplished the redemption. We thank the LORD and his Mother for having agreed to be the *New Adam and Eve*.

<sup>3. cf. [Matt 19:26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+19%3A26&version=RSVCE)</sup>

---

Please see: [CCC 490ff](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p122a3p2.htm#490).

---

**Postscript**

*What was the calling of Eve, what was her glory?*

She was the first woman, [*the mother of all living*](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3%3A20&version=RSVCE), among her children, Mary the Mother of God, and her Son, *the Son of man*<sup>4</sup>.

I am sure Eve is not complaining.

<sup>4. cf. [Matt 8:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+8%3A20&version=RSVCE).</sup>